# How to find online newspaper archives between WW1 to WW2 (1920s and 1930s)

Tags: world-war-two, world-war-one, resource

I can't find any online newspaper archives between World War 1 and World War 2, except for the Chicago Tribune Archives, but their scans are so blurry that most words can't be read.  During the early 1940s, the scans seem to be better quality.  I'm trying to read actual newspaper clippings from the 20s and 30s, particularly matters relating to Germany, or Europe and America in general.

**Edit---** My interest is a love for history and understanding how World-War Issues (post ww1 and pre ww2) were covered/reported (as they occurred) to the public, for example, stories of Adolf Hitler's rise to power as they were reported in American or British newspapers, Mussolini etc.

Comment: Wikipedia has a whole [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:List_of_online_newspaper_archives) of newspaper archives, many of which are online.

Comment: That's quit a complete looking list, and from all over the world.  I'm searching through it now to try to find one that covers world news through the 20s and 30s, in English, and is Free.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility for UK newspapers is the [British Newspaper Archive](http://www.britishnewspaperarchive.co.uk/). They have several subscriptions available and a pay-per-view option.

You can also find some information in the London, Edinburgh and Belfast [Gazettes](https://www.thegazette.co.uk/). These are sources for official UK announcements ("published by Aythority"). You can access historic copies for free.

Several of the genealogy sites, such as [Ancestry](https://www.ancestry.co.uk/) and [FindMyPast](http://www.findmypast.co.uk/) offer newspapers as part of their subscriptions. I'm not sure how well their collection covers the rest of the world. Most of these sites offer periodic free access weekends if you're able to wait.

Family Search has compiled a list of [Digital Historical Newspapers](https://familysearch.org/wiki/en/Digital_Historical_Newspapers).  You can try checking the list for different locations around the world and different time periods.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I like [chroniclingamerica.loc.gov](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/) for some research, but it cuts off at 1924.

Comment: The British Archive looks good, but charges after 3 searches.  Chronicling America has good articles, partial coverage.